# Custom product collection on list.phtml do not outputs price and product name

Tags: magento2, product-list, product-collection

I pass to catalogs list.phtml a custom product collection as

```
    public function getCurrentProduct()
    {
        return $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_product');
    }

    public function _getProductCollection()
    {
        $product = $this->getCurrentProduct();
        if ($product->getTypeId() == \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE) {
            $variants = $this->getProduct()->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProductIds($product);

            $collection = $this->_productsFactory->create();
            $collection->addIdFilter($variants);

            return $collection;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

but on output I do not have price and product name. Can somebody help with this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try add following code before return $collection:

```
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

Answer (score 1):

I reckon you need to add those attributes to select in your collection:

```
$collection = $this->_productsFactory->create();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect(['name','price']);
$collection->addIdFilter($variants);
```

Comment: 'price' is just one field, to get all data connected with special prices etc. '*' would be better in my opinion :)

Comment: @BartłomiejSzubert I reckon the `addAttributeToSelect` method is additive, so both `price` and `name` will be added to the attributes that are added to select by default, I don't think you need the `*` selector

Comment: Maybe you're right, I just assumed that he would like to get data about promotions, and so on. For simply including those attributes to default selected yours answer better.